# Google Drive Open URL development workaround

Tags: google-drive-api

it's possible to setup a Open URL for MIME type support at (console.developer.google.com). That's create and works fine for my application. But only for the product instance at Google Cloud. In detail:

I've released my application in version 1. It's AppEngine base and it supports a Open URL myapp.appspot.com/oauth2callback. So after the release I will going on with feature development for version 2. I use the local AppEngine dev setup. So I take my second client ID and change the Open URL to my local workstation mydev.workstation.com:8080/oauth2callback. That works fine, but it breaks my product instance. Is there any workaround to use Open URL for the production instance and a second Open URL for my dev instance? In my opinion the Drive SDK settings should be:

enable Authentication Production:
  Client ID: xxx
  Additional Scopes:
  Install URL:
  Open URL: https://myapp.appspot.com/oauth2callback

enable Authentication Development:
  Client ID: xxx
  Additional Scopes:
  Install URL:
  Open URL: http://devworkstation.com:8080/oauth2callback

Jens

Answer (score 0):

Create separate projects in the console for prod/qa/dev

Comment: Sure that's possible, but not so beautiful. And different .yaml files for prod/qa/dev/?

Comment: There are some other advantages to doing it, specifically for managing app credentials. Those credentials are sensitive and shouldn't be shared widely. Likewise, the more people who have access to things like the Drive SDK settings and are tweaking URLs for their own environment, the more opportunities there are for somebody to accidentally screw up prod. And for APIs like cloud storage, etc. where data is owned by the app itself, you *really* want to create some isolation so that your not acting on prod data during development.

So yeah, overhead for small teams, but still good practice.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @SteveBazyl is the preferred one for all the reasons stated. A kludgy alternative would be to have the servlet that is bound to the Open URL detect when it is dealing with a test scenario and do a 301 redirect to your dev server.

Also, the API URL is pretty consistent, so once you've sniffed it once, it's not to difficult to path the host and use it in a curl script or browser bookmark for local testing.

As an aside "oauth2callback" is a slightly odd name for your Drive Open URL. It's not wrong, but "driveopen" would show the separate concerns.